# Redirecting example.com/* to www.example.com/*

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

I just moved to a new host and they've got a different control panel than the one I was using before. On my old host, all domain.com/* addresses were 301 redirected to **www.**example.com/*, without me having to configure anything and I'm trying to reproduce this on my current host.

After doing some searching, I found the following .htaccess code, which I put in my site's root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And this works, redirecting all example.com/* pages to www.example.com/*, *except* for when I visit example.com/forum. If I access my forum by visiting www.example.com/forum, for some reason it's redirected to example.com/forum (no www). It didn't do this before.

So then what I did was put a modified version of the above code at the top of my forum's .htaccess file (which is located at /forum), the only difference being the addition of "/forum" on the last line:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/forum/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works, but I'm just wondering if I'm going about doing this "the right way" or there's another way that's superior?

Comment: [RFC 2606](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606), see section 3.

Answer (score 1):

The rules I use in the docroot's .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^[^.]*?\.?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.                         [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://www.%1/$1                [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only one .htaccess in root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: So I just took out the changes I made to /forum/.htaccess, and replaced the redirect in root's .htaccess with the code you gave, and www.domain.com/forum is again redirecting to domain.com/forum, though domain.com/<anything else> is redirecting to www.domain.com/<anything else> properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other rewrite rules in your .htaccess file?
If so, put the first 3 lines that you showed above the other rewrite rules.

When I did this, example.com/xyz redirected to www.example.com/xyz.

My .htaccess file is located in my webroot (/var/ww on Ubuntu Lucid).